# How to change the initial text in Twitter based on what a label says?

Tags: ios, twitter

I have made a random fact generator and was wondering if i could make the initial text in a tweet from the app the same as whatever the label (which is where the fact i going to be displayed when the user pushes a button) says. Help would be greatly appreciated, and i am new semi new to coding but just really need help on this one part. If you need more info about what i am asking just leave a comment. thanks

This is the code that i would use to generate the tweet (if i knew how to make the initial text a variable) What i have with stars around it is what i want to have changed :

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    SLComposeViewController *twitter = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];

    twitter = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [twitter setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"***Say Something***"]];
    [self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];

    [twitter setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        NSString *output;
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                output = @"Action Cancelled";
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                output = @"Tweet Successful!";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Please share the code which you are using right now to generate the tweet, it would help significantly.

Comment: @esqew i uploaded in with the code that i would use if i knew how to change the the initial text based on what the label says.

Comment: @esqew i dont have the code in the project yet becuase there is no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider [reading the manual.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205-CH1-SW10) The line itself is pretty self-explanatory:

```
[twitter setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"***Say Something***"]];
```

Now, all you have to do is change it so that it's sourcing from your label. Assuming your label that you would like to tweet the text from is called `factLabel`, you'd have to do something like this:

```
[twitter setInitialText:factLabel.text];
```